# Is it possible to download theme from wordpress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

Suppose we have designed a Wordpress theme and would like to show it to the customer. Customer wonders how to use the Admin panel to make customization on the theme options (blocks, layouts etc). If I give the admin access to the customer, he would be able to download the theme via full backup (maybe with some other way).

Is it possible to give access to admin panel so that they can do modifications on the site (theme-specific blocks etc) but they can't download the theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable editor in your theme then someone access your all files which has been available in theme folder. So if you want to share your admin panel only then you can hide your editor mode from your theme. Then they will not be able to see your code base.